# Draw circle OpenGL 3.3

Tags: opengl, glsl

How do I draw a perfect/smooth circle using OpenGL 3.3 and GLSL? I can only find old OpenGL tutorials or ones that have a blocky circle. I would also like to be able to resize the circle to become an oval, but that is not my highest priority.

Comment: There are many possibilities. Do you know how to draw a a line, a triangle, a quad ? Vertexbuffer, Index(Element)buffer, primitives, projection, issue draw calls ? How to pass a uniform to the vertex shader (the radius) ? And if you really search you'll find tutorials ...

Comment: I've linked this to an existing Q&A thread we have on drawing smooth circles in OpenGL. If you have any difficulty applying the existing answers to your case, please edit your question to describe how your needs are different from the linked question, and we can re-open it for answers that focus on that new case.